# OneNote 2013 Hyperlinks dont work in pdf-export with FoxitReader

Tags: pdf, microsoft-onenote, foxit-reader, microsoft-onenote-2013

If I export a Page to pdf-Format in onenote2013, the external hyperlinks in the resulting pdf don't work. They are blue and underlined but I can't click them and there is no information about the destination of the link.

Is there any solution to export from onenote to pdf and get working external hyperlinks?
If not, is there a way that the linkdestination is shown instead of the linktext in the pdf-file?

EDIT:
The Problem occurs only with Foxitreader as PDFviewer. In AdobeReader there are no Problems. Even SumatraPDF works well.
There seems to be an security feature of FoxitReader which disables the Hyperlinks. All options I found (JavaScript, Trust Manager) didn't change anything.

Using Foxit Reader 6.1.5.0624.

EDIT 2:
Done a little testing. So in Foxit Reader no Link works. No hyperlinks to websites, files on computer, even the refs to another page or section in the same document won't work.

The Question is why do hyperlinks not work Foxit Reader?

Comment: This is for external hyperlinks, not internal, as indicated? External as in on the internet, or external within your machine? e.g. relative or absolute?

Comment: @Raystafarian I only used links to websites.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  What are you using to both create and view the PDF?

Ensure that you are doing an "export" and not a "print":  File / Export / "PDF (*.pdf)".

For viewing, I am able to see and use an active link using both (Microsoft) Reader and Adobe (Acrobat) Reader.

Comment: I used the native expport function of OneNote. No additional software or printing. On the other hand I used FoxIt Reader for viewing.

Comment: Tested it this evening on another machine with OneNote 2010 and AdobeReader and it works! Confusing! Will test with the first setup again but AdobeReader tomorrow. (PS: Comment-Editing isn't easy :P)

Comment: Tested with OneNote2013 and AdobeReader -> works! But FoxitReader wont work with the same file.

Comment: @RoKi0815 - Then the next question is, does your version of FoxitReader work links as expected in any PDF file?